# How can I pass an array from view to controller?

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Sorry, I know that may be a duplicate question. 
I have already founded the information but really don't know how to do that.

I want to pass an array from view to controller. Below is the code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FinishExam", "Exams"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    List<int> answerArray = new List<int>();

    for (var i = 0; i <= examMulQuestion.Count - 1; i = i + 3)
    {
        int questionId = examMulQuestion[i].questionId;

            <h4> @questionNo . @examMulQuestion[i].questionContent</h4>
        questionNo++;

            <li style="">
                <input type="radio" name="answerArray[@answerNo]" value="@examMulQuestion[i].answerId">       @examMulQuestion[i].answerContent <br />
                <input type="radio" name="answerArray[@answerNo]" value="@examMulQuestion[i + 1].answerId"> @examMulQuestion[i + 1].answerContent <br />
                <input type="radio" name="answerArray[@answerNo]" value="@examMulQuestion[i + 2].answerId"> @examMulQuestion[i + 2].answerContent
            </li>
        answerNo++;
        <br /><br />
    }
}

<input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default">
```

I used `answerArray[@answerNo]` as the array such as `answerArray[0]`, `answerArray[1]`, etc, I don't know how to pass the array to the controller, because when the button submits and the controller show the array is `null`

```
public ActionResult FinishExam(List<int> answerArray) (shows null)
{
    return View();
}
```

I tried to use ajax, but i am a beginner don't know how to do that .

```
function submit() {
    $.ajax({
        url: ('/Exams/FinishExam'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: answerArray,
        dataType: 'JSON'
    });
}
```

Would you show me the way? BIG THANKS!!

Comment: In your js code what is `answerArray`? Can you show that code please.

Comment: I haven't declared answerArray in js code, but in the View, the code is List<int> answerArray = new List<int>();

Comment: The only way that `List<int> answerArray` in the controller POST method can be `null` is if your have not selected a radio button in the first group (the `DefaultModelBinder` required collection indexers start at zero and be consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will fulfil your condition.Kindly check it.

```
                         var id=new Array();
                          $.each($(".listCheckBox"), function(i){   

                              if($(this).prop('checked')==true){

                                  var splitid = $(this).val();
                                  var splittedid = splitid.split('~-1~-1`');
                                 id.push(splittedid[0]);

                              }
                         });
```

Comment: is that I can put this code into the function submit() to replace my original code, and trigger the function by <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="submit" onclick="submit()">

Comment: You can put this code into function of jquery and run that that function on onClick of submit function And after you put this code into the function. Now run the ajax to send your all data to the controller.Put your id's which you pushed into array by push method into data of ajax and get it to the controller.Your work will done and if there any issue then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `answerArray` is only accessible in the backend code on the server. You cannot access it from JavaScript. If you use the debugger (Chrome Debugger or another web debugger) you will notice that `answerArray` is not defined. Here is one way you can achieve what you need. In your view add this code:

```
<script>
    var answerArray = 
        @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(answerArray));
</script>
```

Now it will serialize the c# variable `answerArray` and assign it to a JavaScript variable named `answerArray`. You can then use it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion.

First create a Model or View Model for your this Page View:

```
public class ExamModel
{

    public virtual string questionContent { get; set; }

    public virtual int questionId { get; set; }

    public virtual int answerId { get; set; }

    public virtual string answerContent { get; set; }
}
```

Then populate it before rendering the view:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IList<ExamModel> lstModel = new List<ExamModel>();
        lstModel.Add(new ExamModel()
        {
            questionContent = "Test Question1",
            questionId = 1,
            answerId = 101,
            answerContent = "Answer Test101"
        });
        lstModel.Add(new ExamModel()
        {
            questionContent = "Test Question2",
            questionId = 2,
            answerId = 102,
            answerContent = "Answer Test102"
        });

        return View(lstModel);
    }
```

Pass it to your razor view using:

```
@model IList<SPiGlobal.PR.Web.Models.ExamModel>
```

Then on your for loop:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FinishExam", "SO"))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

for (var i = 0; i <= Model.Count - 1; i++){
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Model[i].questionContent
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model[i].answerId, Model[i].answerId, true) @examMulQuestion[i].answerContent  
    </div>
   }
<input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default">
}
```

Take note that make sure your submit button Is inside your BeginForm since its not working for me when its outside the BeginForm:

```
<input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default">
```

This is just a suggestion, here is the screenshot of the PostBack:

[image]